# System crashes while accessing SharePoint 2007 Links

Tags: 2007, administration, office-integration, office-web-apps

User is running on XP, IE6.0 with Office 2003.

Whenever tries to access any of the SharePoint 2007 Links, Either system goes down or application closes automatically.

Have you ever come across such an issue  ?

Comment: What kind of error messages (if any) do you see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try disabling all browser add-ins and reenable them one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be this?

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/923996